# setting key to object when writing data in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning how to add data to firebase database on a click event.

So far i was able to add data to database but i'm facing issue of setting the correct key for the data object i'm pushing.

For example i have a firebase database in the following structure

```
appName

  labels

  products

     0
     1
     2
     3

  names
```

Here in the `products` 0,1,2,3 are data objects. i want to add more data objects to `products` .

My approach was as follows

```
export const addProduct = () => {
   firebase.database().ref('products').push({
      category: "Tech",
      rate: "$10 for 15min",
      review: {},
      title: ""
   });
}
```

And in the view when the user clicks on a button i'm calling the above function

```
addData() {
   addProduct();
}
```

Data is added to `products` but the issue is key for that object is some random characters. How can i set the key for this object as  `4` and increment the key as i add more data.?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not the recommended way of dealing with lists of data in Realtime Database.  I suggest giving up on the idea that you can work with numeric indexes, and instead just push() everything and accept the random ID.  if you want to impose order on your child values, you should use property in the child to order them.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: when i push with random ID for some reason i cannot read the values from firebase. I can see that i have pushed everything correctly. But it breaks my existing UI which is rendered by mapping these data.